# Finding Lines of all Angles in 2D Array of Ints

Tags: function, line, formula, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D Array of integers where 0=white and 1=black such as the following:

```
1110001
0110000
0011000
0101100
0100110
0100011
1000001
1011000
1011000
```

I want to find all black lines in the array. I do not just want vertical horizontal and diagonal with slope of 1. I can do all of these things. I want a way to find lines of all slopes (it can include the ways that I already do it to lessen code). So, if you look at the 2D array, you can see a line with a slope of 3 starting at [0,8] (Bottom Left Corner), and going to [2,0] (Top middle). I have looked at several other listings, but they seem to only look for the things I am already able to do, or do not give ways to find these lines.

I am coding in Java, but C++ code, or just a logical explanation would also be welcomed.

If my description is still too broad, think of it this way: I want to be able to find every line that can be created using the line tool in paint.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm wondering if looking at gaming bot pathing algorithms might have something to offer you? For detecting gradient lines you'd need to keep a count of the number of pixels in either horizontal or vertical directions, but I'm not sure how you'd handle the ends as they'd likely have a different number of pixels in a row than the rest of the line. So for example, to start off with you might have 3 pixels down, then 1 across then 4 pixels down 1 across (repeated several times) then maybe 2 pixels down at the finishing end.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but please correct me if I'm mistaken. I should look for patterns of say vertical lines that are 3 pixels long, and connect ones that are adjacent. So in my example, I would have 3 lines that are adjacent, and I can combine them to one line. The 3 v. 4 v. 2 long should not be an issue as I can just find adjacent lines with the same slope. I would just have to figure out a way to combine lines with one pixel long segments.

Comment: Thinking about this further, if you want accuracy over speed, then you could forwardly decide on all lines possible from each pixel to every other pixel in the array, calculate the line mathematically then compare the results to the contents of the array. If all pixels are a match then the line is valid. That way you are building a pretty basic anti-aliasing method to work out which pixels fit a line. Computationally, a very expensive method though I guess.

Comment: I think the problem with the 3v4v2 is working out if those segments have the same slope. You could have a line with mainly 4 in 1 slope, but if the ends have only 3 segments it calculate as a different slope, or may match a different line also coming from the same location that has a 3 in 1 slope.

Comment: I can afford for it to be a little expensive, but not quite that expensive. I am going to have this working on a mobile device for a game. If need be, I can require the user to go to a spot in the game to upload the array to a server for calculations, and then notify them upon completion, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: As for the 3v4v2, I will be doing 3 calculation before I invoke this. I will go through and find vertical, horizontal, and diagonal with slope of 1 lines and put them in a list. Then I will combine them if they are adjacent and in the same list. I think that would solve that problem. That would only leave a problem of a 1 long middle segment. I can use your prediction logic for ends. That will be easier than the prediction for the whole thing.

Comment: Also, consider the line that runs from 0,3 to 7,5. It doesn't look that straight because of the top end having an extra pixel, but if continued in a repeated way would in fact represent a straight line with an awkward alignment to the grid (every so often you need 1 extra height ... so something like a 1 in 17 slope).

Comment: I wonder though if there is a way to do a variation of your prediction that is much lighter. Something like taking a pixel and looking for adjacent (Meaning horizontal, vertical, or diagonal pixels). Then looking for horizontal, vertical or diagonal pixels in the same direction. Would there be a way to do this that is not extremely expensive?

Comment: As for that 0,3 to 7,5 line, I was going to deal with that at a later time, and at this stage just consider it two diagonal lines with a -1 slope, and then an extra pixel that is unimportant for the lines. I plan to find simple shapes after I find lines, so I guess this stage would only be looking for lines that have a thickness of 1 pixel.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the thickness so much as the little blip near the end. Any slope detection will need to account for the occasional 'blip' in the expected number of pixels. Consider a line that has a slope of 3 in 7. Every now and then there will need to be a odd pixel to make up for the fact that you can't split the pixels. Drawing that line is one thing but detecting it is something else!

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I'll try to play around with some of the stuff you mentioned and see what I can come up with. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that will get at least most of the lines I am looking for at a reasonable cost, relatively speaking. Comment on any flaws in this solution please.

1. Find All horizontal, vertical, and perfectly diagonal lines (Slope of 1 or -1).
   Will explain for horizontal lines to simplify, but the same can be applied, with small tweeks to diagonal and vertical lines.
2. Check to see if right-most point has an adjacent point to the top right or top. (Do same for bottom right or bottom).
3. If adjacent point up, check moving backward in list of lines from current point for a line with a start point that is equal to adjacent point. (Do the same going forward in list for bottom right or bottom point.)
4. Stop when line is found or when Y is 2 or more away from current line.
5. Check to see if end point of current line is end point of a line in new list (list with lines made up of multiple horizontal lines). If so, add new line (line found in step 4) to this line. (This will prevent overlapping lines.
6. If Y is 2 or more away in step 4 (end of line, no connection) Add line to master list.
7. After all horizontal lines have been iterated through, add new list to master list.
8. Repeat 2-7 with adjustments where needed, and after completion, master list should be complete.
   The only overlapping that should be from vertical lines and horizontal lines making squares, or something similar, but no overlap of horizontal lines or near horizontal lines should occur.

Please let me know if there are any flaws in this logic, and, if possible, please suggest an alternative.

Comment: That seems a reasonable approach, although I think it may allow it to pick up quite wobbly lines (maybe this is desirable?). I'm not totally understanding what you mean in step 3 though. I suppose if you only want to pick up straight lines you could check whether the line is straight or not after detecting the whole length of line, by creating a straight line from start and end positions and comparing that to what is in the array. Also, when detecting horizontal lines, isn't there a danger of it picking up the middle of a line with a shallow slope? therefore splitting the line into segments?

Comment: So, for the prevention of wobbly lines, I am also storing the slope of a line. If it is positive, then I will only look at the pixel above it and above and to the right of it. I am only ever storing the first and last point, so yes it may be a little wobbly, but, the change in angles, if I am doing it correctly, will always be less than 23 degrees. I'm okay with that amount of wobble. As for picking up in the middle, I only keep the start and end points of a line, so, in the end I have the simplest data to work with. This is because I don't need to be exact in the shapes.

Comment: As for your question about what is occurring in step 3, I will have a list of horizontal lines from 0 to N where C is my current location in the list at any given time. The list will be sorted by starting point from how I iterate through to create the list. So, I know that if I am searching for a pixel above the current line, I can start my search from C and work toward 0 until I either hit 0 or I find a pixel that is in the row above what I am looking for, or even anywhere before what I'm looking for. This will cut down my search time significantly, and will only happen if a pixel is there.